# restore all mysql database from a --all-database sql.gz file

Tags: backup, mysql, database-restore

I've backed all my mysql databases with he following command

```
mysqldump -u root -ppasswod --all-databases | gzip > all.sql.gz
```

just wanted to know will I be able to restore all of the database with  following command

```
gunzip < alldb.sql.gz | mysql -u root -ppassword -h localhost
```

can you also tell me how to back up all of mysql users too?

I cant test it because I'm not sure and I don't want to break any db on my current system

Answer (score 58):

Yes. Generally, to restore compressed backup files you can do the following:

```
gunzip < alldb.sql.gz | mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname]
```

Please consult [How to Back Up and Restore a MySQL Database](http://web.archive.org/web/20210419001207/http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php)

Note that the `--all-databases` option is applicable to backup only. The backup file itself will contain all the relevant `CREATE DATABASE quux;` commands for the restore.

Comment: nothing is mentioned about restoring databases from an all_db.sql.gz file

Comment: haha I know that.
what I meant was that they havent specified how to restore from an --all-databse backup

Comment: Your --all-database output file should contain the necessary `CREATE DATABASE foo;` commands for the backed up dbs, so when you restore from it, all the databases will be restored. You can open the `all.sql` file and grep for these commands to make sure all the dbs are mentioned.

Comment: yea it's there
I just wanted to confirm the way in which I should restore after a fresh MySQL installation what is the command that can be used for importing DB all at once from my alldb file

Comment: It seems that I'm stuck in these problem as well. I've backup more than 50 databases using --all-databases dump. And now i need to manually identify those databases instead of 1 import command.

Comment: Well running your command get me error 'ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'MY_DB_NAME'. Do we have to create the database first?

Comment: And when dropping the database name, it raise 'ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected'. I guess my backup script don't create the database first.

Comment: This command removes original .gz file. What If I want to keep backup file?

Answer (score 14):

**This is the command I use to backup all databases in MySQL:**

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p --all-databases --events --ignore-table=mysql.event --extended-insert --add-drop-database --disable-keys --flush-privileges --quick --routines --triggers | gzip > "all_databases.gz"
```

- The '--all-databases' option tells the command to include all of the databases.  If you want to specify one or more then remove that option and replace it with '--databases dbname1 dbname2 dbnameX'
- To backup all of your mysql users, passwords, permissions then include the 'mysql' database in your backup.  The --all-databases option includes this database in the backup.
- The '--routines' option includes stored procedures and functions in the backup.
- The '--triggers' option includes any triggers in the backup.

**To restore from a *.gz mysqldump file:**

```
gunzip < all_databases.gz | mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

Answer (score 12):

**To display a progress bar while importing a sql.gz file, download pv and use the following:**

pv mydump.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root -p

**If PV command is not installed on your system then try below command relatively**

**In CentOS/RHEL**

yum install pv

**In Debian/Ubuntu**

apt-get install pv

**In MAC**

brew install pv

**Output Something like that  -->**

pv mydump.sql.gz  | gunzip | mysql -u root -p dbname

Enter password:

255MiB 0:05:49 [ 748kiB/s] [===========>             ] 30%

Comment: If you're referring to an already posted answer, please include the link to the original. Answer copied from: https://serverfault.com/a/445130/275858

Comment: Okay but i have not copied anything from anywhere if you think so you can take help from there

Comment: `pv` is a truly incredible gem